# Accessing a window with pdf file from a cross-domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have a web app (for example, running local): frontend on http://localhost:8080 and backend on http://localhost:59922. And there is a service that returns pdf files, like http://myserver/pdfservice/12345.pdf. I'm trying to open pdf file in new window and call print dialog:

```
let window = window.open("http://myserver/pdfservice/12345.pdf"); 
window.print();
```

but getting error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

If window is opened from http://localhost:59922 then there is the same problem. I've even added header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*"` to response but it didn't help. I found here answers only about iframes, but I not have any iframe.

Answer (score 0):

to do this , first you will need to install pdf viewer on your pc like adobe acrobat
then , make sure you set the proper permission for the folders where you placing the pdf files .
and to get of this error , you may want to avoid opening the pdf file into popup window , let it open within the same page ,

also incase you want to open the pdf from your root folder 
make sure you have the pdf file there along on that folder and again do not forget to set the permission .

here is example :

```
 <object height="950" data="sample-report.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="860">
 <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
 No biggie... you can <a href="sample-report.pdf">click here to
 download the PDF file.</a>
 </p>
 </object>
```

Open a PDF file to a specific page 
To target an HTML link to a specific page in a PDF file, add #page=[page number] to the end of the link's URL.
For example, this HTML tag opens page 4 of a PDF file named myfile.pdf:

Note: If you use UNC server locations (\servername\folder) in a link, set the link to open to a set destination using the procedure in the following section. If you use URLs containing local hard drive addresses (c:\folder), you cannot link to page numbers or set destinations. With Adobe Acrobat 7.0 products, a link to a page number works only if you use HTTP or HTTPS locations. UNC server locations will only work if you use the set destinations method outlined in the following section of this document.

Comment: I'm not using folders and not have pdf files on local drives, all happens on the fly via http.

Comment: it doesn't matter using local or external is same but am just saying if u r using ur local u need to check the permission

Comment: that error says the site u r trying to view the pdf file from it is not allowing you to view its content so try to open the pdf through your local drive and see if the error is gone … good luck anyways